# Karate Framework- AWS Auth throwing error "the request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided"

Tags: aws-api-gateway, karate

I'm getting "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided" error for the following Code used in the Karate framework. Please help me to fix it.

**My Feature File:**

```
Feature: Functional validations for  API
  Background: 
    * configure headers = { Content-Type: 'application/json',x-api-key: 'apikeyValue' }
  Scenario: Verify if  API response is success

    Scenario Outline: Initial test

    * def userdir = karate.properties['user.dir']
    * def reusableMethod =  function() { var JavaDemo = Java.type('runner.Signature'); jd = new JavaDemo(); return jd.getSignature(); }

    * def reusableMethod2 =  function() { var JavaDemo2 = Java.type('runner.Signature'); jd = new JavaDemo2(); return jd.getDateString(); }
    * def token = call reusableMethod
    * def date = call reusableMethod2
    Given url baseUrl
    And header Authorization = token
    And header X-Amz-Date = date
    * def requestjson = read('file:' +userdir+'<readRequest>')
    When request requestjson
    And set requestjson.header.applicationId = '<applicationId>'
    And method POST
    Then status 200

    Examples: 
      | readRequest                         | applicationId |
      | /src/test/java/resources/input.json | abc           |
```

**My runner.Signature Class:**

```
public  String getDateString() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        DateFormat dfm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'");
        dfm.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));  //server timezone
        return dfm.format(cal.getTime());
    }
    public String getSignature() throws URISyntaxException {
    
    String contentSha256 = "sampleValue";
    String ACCESS_KEY = "accesskeyValue";
    String SECRET_KEY = "SecretKeyValue";
    
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest("GET", new URI("UrlValue"));

    AwsCredentials awscred = new AwsCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY);
    
    
      String signature1 = Signer.builder()
                .awsCredentials(awscred)
                .region("regionValue")
                .header("content-type","application/json")
                .header("host", "HostValue") 
                .header("x-api-key", "apikeyValue") 
                .header("x-amz-date", getDateString())
                .header("x-amz-content-sha256", contentSha256) 
                .build(request,"execute-api", contentSha256) 
                .getSignature();
                        
return signature1;
```

Comment: if the linked answer does not help, follow this process please: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue